# Is there a way to count historical data?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table like this:

| mnfct | type | receipt_date | sold_date | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Asus | lp1 | 4/11/2021 |  | open |
| Epson | tv1 | 3/8/2021 | 4/1/2021 | closed |
| Bosch | wm1 | 2/5/2021 | 2/15/2021 | closed |
| Asus | sf1 | 1/7/2021 | 2/10/2021 | closed |
| Epson | tv2 | 5/12/2021 |  | open |
| Bosch | wc1 | 10/12/2021 |  | open |

Each manufacturer has a lot of types. When the sold_date is NULL, then status is OPEN.
I need to count each OPEN entry for each Manufacturer per month. But columns sold_date and receipt_date could change, a person could manually change dates. So I need to count to count open entries, at the moment of the month. For instance, if I am counting for May, then I need to define and count only open entries at the end of the May. If user changed the dates after the 31st of May but it happened in May, it should be counted.

Is there a way to do that? Is Oracle logging change records in any way?

Comment: You are talking about "Oracle Flashback Technology" (https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/adfns/flashback.html). Oracle does implement them by appending `AS OF` to the `SELECT` query. However, it does require configuration. You'll need at least to specify the data retentiion policy.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to count using SQL query?

Comment: Oracle Flashback Technology is used in SQL queries. Just add `AS OF` at the end of the SQL query.